# Change Content Type for files in Azure Storage Blob

Tags: windows, azure, storage, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I use only Microsoft Azure Storage and no other Azure products/services.  I upload files to my storage blob via ftp type client (GoodSync), and I need to change the content type of all the files based on their file extension after they are already in the Blob.  I have looked around and have not found out how to do this without having one of their VPS with PowerShell. What are my options and how do I accomplish this?  I really need step by step here.

Comment: Which programming language do you use? Look for language specific storage client library and find function to update blob properties (The property you would want to update is Content-Type). You can run the code from your computer. No need to get other Azure Services.

Comment: I use ASP, but with step by step instructions, I can do anything. I am computer savy, just need directions on what to do/run/install on my computer.

Comment: I think it would be too much to explain. I think it would be just easier if you use one of the available storage explorers and change the blob's content type property or do a search for "azure blob change content type" and I'm sure you will find a lot of examples.

Comment: I need to change 90,000+ files, and growing by thousands each month

Comment: Aah ... in this case it might be tricky to update the content type manually using a tool. Give me some time and I will provide some code (in case nobody else beats me to it :)). But for future, try to use a tool like AzCopy to upload blobs which sets the blob content at the time of uploading only.

Comment: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/  Here, I don't see anything about setting up content type.

Answer (score 5):

I recently had the same issue so I created a simple utility class in order to "fix" content type based on file's extension. You can read details [here](http://ppolyzos.com/2015/10/27/apply-proper-content-type-to-files-in-azure-storage-containers-based-on-file-extensions/)

What you need to do is parse each file in your Azure Storage Containers and update ContentType based on a dictionary that defines which MIME type is appropriate for each file extension.

```
// Connect to your storage account
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);

// Load Container with the specified name 
private CloudBlobContainer GetCloudBlobContainer(string name)
{
    CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = _storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    return cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(name.ToLowerInvariant());
}
```

```
// Parse all files in your container and apply proper ContentType
private void ResetContainer(CloudBlobContainer container)
{
    if (!container.Exists()) return;

    Trace.WriteLine($"Ready to parse {container.Name} container");
    Trace.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------");

    var blobs = container.ListBlobs().ToList();

    var total = blobs.Count;
    var counter = 1;

    foreach (var blob in blobs)
    {
        if (blob is CloudBlobDirectory) continue;

        var cloudBlob = (CloudBlob)blob;

        var extension = Path.GetExtension(cloudBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri);

        string contentType;
        _contentTypes.TryGetValue(extension, out contentType);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType)) continue;

        Trace.Write($"{counter++} of {total} : {cloudBlob.Name}");
        if (cloudBlob.Properties.ContentType == contentType)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine($" ({cloudBlob.Properties.ContentType}) (skipped)");
            continue;
        }

        cloudBlob.Properties.ContentType = contentType;
        cloudBlob.SetProperties();
        Trace.WriteLine($" ({cloudBlob.Properties.ContentType}) (reset)");
    }
}
```

`_contentTypes` is a dictionary that contains the appropriate MIME type for each file extension:

```
    private readonly Dictionary _contentTypes = new Dictionary()
    {
        {".jpeg", "image/jpeg"},
        {".jpg", "image/jpeg" }
    };
```

Full list of content types and source code can be found [here](https://github.com/ppolyzos/AzStorage.Utilities).

Comment: There is a method built into .net to get the content type for you.
System.Web.MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(string fileName);

Answer (score 0):

Here you are a refreshed version for latest Azure.Storage.Blobs SDK. I'm using .Net 5 and console app.

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

var contentTypes = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {".woff", "font/woff"},
    {".woff2", "font/woff2" }
};

var cloudBlobClient = new BlobServiceClient("connectionstring");
var cloudBlobContainerClient = cloudBlobClient.GetBlobContainerClient("fonts");
await cloudBlobContainerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

var blobs = cloudBlobContainerClient.GetBlobsAsync();

await foreach (var blob in blobs)
{
    var extension = Path.GetExtension(blob.Name);

    contentTypes.TryGetValue(extension, out var contentType);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType)) continue;

    if (blob.Properties.ContentType == contentType)
    {
        continue;
    }

    try
    {
        // Get the existing properties
        var blobClient = cloudBlobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blob.Name);
        var properties = await blobClient.GetPropertiesAsync();

        var headers = new BlobHttpHeaders
        {
            ContentType = contentType,
            CacheControl = properties.CacheControl,
            ContentDisposition = properties.ContentDisposition,
            ContentEncoding = properties.ContentEncoding,
            ContentHash = properties.ContentHash,
            ContentLanguage = properties.ContentLanguage
        };

        // Set the blob's properties.
        await blobClient.SetHttpHeadersAsync(headers);
    }
    catch (RequestFailedException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"HTTP error code {e.Status}: {e.ErrorCode}");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking to do this in PowerShell here is a very remedial version of [martonx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65910256/13390888) with no error handling but it works to set the content type of all blobs in a container:

```
if(!(Get-Module Az -ListAvailable)) { Install-Module -Name Az }
$containerName = '<name of the container>'
$contentTypes = @{
    '.ps1' = 'text/plain'
    '.py' = 'text/plain'
    '.bat' = 'text/plain'
}
$context = New-AzStorageContext -ConnectionString '<connection string>'
$blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Context $context -Container $containerName
foreach ($blob in $blobs) {
    $extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($blob.Name)
    $contentType = $contentTypes[$extension]
    if ($contentType) {
        $properties = $blob.BlobClient.GetProperties().Value
        if ($contentType -ne $properties.ContentType) {
            $blobHeaders = @{
                ContentType = $contentType
                CacheControl = $properties.CacheControl
                ContentDisposition = $properties.ContentDisposition
                ContentEncoding = $properties.ContentEncoding
                ContentHash = $properties.ContentHash
                ContentLanguage = $properties.ContentLanguage
            }
            $blob.BlobClient.SetHttpHeaders($blobHeaders)
        }
    }
}
```